# Android Runtime - Fatal Exception: main + error from decompiled phonegap build apk

Tags: android, cordova, build, runtime

I developed an app using HTML + JQUERY mobile and package it using PhoneGap Build. After it was package as an APK, I decompile it using apktool to be open on Eclipse as an "Android Project from Existing Code". However, whenever I tried to run the app, the LogCat produces "Android Runtime - Fatal Exception: main" at the same time the app stopped unexpectedly and force close.
I hope somebody have the similar problem from phonegap Build that can share me the solution.
Will greatly appreciate anybody's help.
cheers.

Comment: why on earth would you do that? If you want to debug locally, use cordova or phonegap locally, not phonegap build!

Comment: Hi QuickFix, thnks for the suggestion. But for my workflow, I think it is best for me to use PhoneGap Build since most of my contents are HTML + jquery mobile. I find it much easy to develop an app from my html pages using phonegap Build. But since I plan to add coding on my apk, I plan to open it on Eclipse and do the job in there.

Comment: sorry to say that sounds just nonsense... but good luck anyway.

Comment: and a bit of a background, the main reason I want to edit it on Eclipse is that I just found out that it will be difficult/impossible to apply APK Expansion using the PhoneGap Build.

Comment: Hi QuickFix, will appreaciate if you can give me some tips on dealing HTML + JQuery mobile apps in Eclipse. Im willing to send you my apk file with if you want to look at it and see if you can run it on eclipse. many thanks.

Comment: what I would do is create a new app in cordova using the --copy-from parameter to integrate the html/js/... from your app, build the app and then import to eclipse (or Android Studio if you use latest cordova version).

Comment: Im quite new to cordova/phonegap and was spoiled using the Build. Please help me examine my apk file. will really appreciate it. thanks.

Comment: Hi QuickFix, feel free to access the decompiled apk file and see if you can run it on Eclipse. many thanks. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw-KXYvjYhfGRHUyaFZ6T2RDSFE&authuser=1)